# Android Listview onListItemClick get Sqlite Id

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I am simply displaying a list from sqlite table. I have not used any BDHelper class. With this code only how can i get id.

[image]

When i click on 1st Item, it shows 0 where as in table it's id is 1. Below is my code.

```
SQLiteDatabase myDB;
        try {
            myDB = openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME,
                    SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);          
            myDB.execSQL("create table if not exists " + COUNTRY_TABLE
            + "(country_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + "country_title text," 
            + "country_status int(11));");          

             /*myDB.execSQL("insert into " + COUNTRY_TABLE +" values "+
             "(null,'India',1)," +
             "(null,'China',1)," +
             "(null,'Australia',1)," +
             "(null,'Japan',1)," +
             "(null,'Germany',1)");*/


            Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("select country_id,country_title from "
                    + COUNTRY_TABLE + " where country_status=1", null);
            if (c != null) {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("country_id"));
                        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("country_title"));                       
                        clist.add(id + ") " + name);
                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                    //int itemcount = clist.size();
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, itemcount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, clist));
                }
            }

        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, se.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(id),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Please suggest what should i do to get the id fron table and not the position.

Comment: you can use CursorAdapter or another ArrayList for storing Country id's and then retrieve using Item click positions as `country_ids.get(id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not possible the way i wanted it but got its solution some other way. While in cursor loop, adding data to list, take another ArrayList and add only id to it.

```
clist1.add(id);
```

Now, on onListItemClick, you can get the position of the item. So, use this position and get the id from the other ArrayList clist1

```
int country_id=clist1[position];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

try below code:

Put your id and name data in clist ArrayList, generate getter, setter method first, set your id and name in that method when myou get that data, each time add that data in ArrayList and then use it like below.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,clist.get(position).getId(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: i made another samle with custom code. check code below:
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) 
{
    int id=arg0.getId();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
In toast, it comes, false and not id.

Comment: you have to get your id from your sqlite data. Store that data in arraylist or hashmap and then get like this ways: int id=arraylist.get(arg2); You will get it for sure.

Comment: i cannot post whole code in comment box so i am posting answer which i will remove. plz check my answer.

Comment: int id=list_data.get(arg2).getId(); write this line.

Comment: it gives this error. android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x3

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<Emp> AllRecords() 
{
    List<Emp> dataset = new ArrayList<Emp>();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_EMPLOYEE,allColumns, null, null,null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Emp obj = cursorToContact(cursor);
        dataset.add(obj);
      cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return dataset;
}

private Emp cursorToContact(Cursor cursor) 
{
    Emp obj = new Emp();
    obj.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
    obj.setName(cursor.getString(1));
    obj.setDesig(cursor.getString(2));
    return obj;
}


//--------------
list_data = (ArrayList<Emp>) qh.AllRecords();
CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(MainActivity.this,list_data);
//---------
int id=list_data.get(arg2); //Type mismatch: cannot convert from Emp to int
```

Plz tell what should i write to get country id.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as how there is no accepted answer...
I did this and it seemed to work.

I'm using a ListView Activity, SQLiteDatabase and an ArrayAdapter

In my onListItemClick method, I instantiate a new object and make it equal to whatever item is at that current position in my adapter.
Task task = adapter.getItem(arg3);

In my task class, I have a private variable of type long called id, as well as a setter and getter for that variable.

Hence, I can then do this:
long taskId = task.getId();

Checking this result with Toast yielded the id generated by SQLite NOT the position in the ListView, which is what I needed.

Hope this helps someone out!

Answer (score 0):

`((TextView)v).getText();` by using this we will get the text of view, then we can query to the table again to get id of the corresponding  text and toast it.

```
 String country_title=((TextView)v).getText();

 Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("select country_id from "+ COUNTRY_TABLE + " where  country_title='"+country_title+"'", null);
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,c.getString(c.getColumnIndexorThrow("country_title")),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: i think its not the proper way as in here i will have to fire query and fetch from table so will increase response time. Also, in any other scenario if titles are same, then multiple records will be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

you can set tag on list item with the id after which you can call getTag() on onItemClick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a couple years late, but it might help someone else: basically set the tag wherever you're setting the individual views.

```
  // Find fields to populate in inflated template

    TextView productName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
    TextView productPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
    TextView productQuantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_quantity);

    // Extract properties from cursor

    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ProductDbContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_NAME));
    int price = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ProductDbContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRICE));
    int quantity = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ProductDbContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_QUANTITY));
    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ProductDbContract.ProductEntry.ID));

    // Set Tag
    productName.setTag(id);
```

and then later you can access it by calling on getTag():

```
    int id = (Integer)((TextView)findViewById(R.id.product_name)).getTag();

    Log.d("LETSEE",String.valueOf(id));
```